# Using takeUntil on inner observable

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

How to write this snippet better?

What I'm trying to achieve is to start a new polling (and discard the previous one) each time `eventGenerator$` emits something, but the polling can be discarded also by other notifier (`anotherEvent$`)

```
this.eventGenerator.asObservable()
  .subscribe(event => {
    if (this.polling$) {
      this.polling$.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.polling$ = timer(0, 1000)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.service.getSomething())
        takeUntil(this.anotherEvent$)
      )
      .subscribe();
  })
```

One of the basic rules is to not subscribe to other subscription inside subscribe() method. 
For this `switchMap` operator sounds like a good choice to chain it but if `takeUntil` is used and the `anotherEvent$` emits it will unsubscribe the whole subscription and not only the polling part, so another emit of `eventGenerator` won't be handled anymore and will not create another timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just restructure your operators:

```
this.eventGenerator$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.service.getSomething()),
    takeUntil(this.anotherEvent$),
  ),
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I fount the issue... I had it like you proposed but the `anotherEvent$` was ReplaySubject so it was always right away unsubscribed after it once emitted, therefore I thought my thinking was wrong.